# qgis unable to connect to ms sql server using sql authentication

Tags: qgis, sql-server

I am getting the following error when I try to set up a connection to a MS SQL Server database using sql server authentication. I did find a bug report from 2014, but that was apparently fixed and closed.

[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed QODBC3: Unable to connect

Database connection works fine for lots of other software, so all the databasee connection settings are good.

I have unchecked "Trusted Connection" and the "test connect" is successful. When I actually try to connect in the "ADD MSSQL Table(s)" form, it throws the error.

Any idea, please?